# Custom Format cells to add a sentence using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro to custom format a cell in such a way, that if someone types a number in the cell (say 10 for example), the output should be "10% of EBITDA margin". How do I do this?

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. You don't need VBA. In fact, VBA would be the wrong solution. Learn about number formats.

Comment: I need the VBA code for this sir... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this VBA code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyRNG As Range: Set MyRNG = Range("B2:B20") 'change your required range here
If Not Application.Intersect(MyRNG, Target) Is Nothing Then
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0.00 ""of EBITDA margin"""
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It will be better if next time you try your coding first & then ask for guidance.

Comment: I did try it but wasn't able to reach anywhere with it. I don't think you would want me or any other user here for that matter to post anything that we might have written... But I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom NumberFormat for the cell (Format Cells > Number > Custom), like

```
0.00% "of EBITDA margin"
```

The `0.00%` part can be any format you want for the number. The space following it can be inside the quotation marks or before them. The quotation marks can contain any string you want, a single word or a long sentence (likely, not more than 255 characters in total, though).

The code below would format Cell A1 with the same NumberFormat shown above. The format could be modified similarly, too.

```
Private Sub SetCellFormat()

    Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "0.00% ""of EBITDA margin"""
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? It works for me. What do you enter in the cell, what is the output format you get?

Comment: My answer does exactly what you specify. Your question doesn't contain sufficient information to create a solution in VBA. I suggest you review your question to eliminate the discrepancies.

Comment: ??? My question is as simple as it can get. What you just achieved doing manually, I need to be able to write a macro for it. I don't know if I can explain it in more simpler terms...

Comment: A macro would need to know the address of the cell you want formatted. Depending upon the use of the macro that address could be absolute or generic. Therefore, if you provide the address VBA could be written. If the address isn't always the same much more information is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189286/discussion-between-totalgadha-and-variatus).